# Database abstraction layer for AIR (JS)?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, air, adobe

I was wondering if there are any abstraction layers for the SQLite database thats integrated into Adobe AIR.

I don't expect something like Doctrine or Zend_Db (coming from the PHP world) but a bit more abstraction and comfort would be really nice.

I'm using the HTML/JavaScript flavor of AIR so any ActionScript stuff is of no use to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used this, but [ActiveRecordJS](http://activerecordjs.org/record.html) supports SQLite for AIR.

Comment: That looks pretty promising, I'll give it a try.